# How do you detach and re-attach items with different classes on different lists using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a page with a dropdown selector and three separate lists, where selecting an option on the dropdown would do a `detach()` on all the items on each list except for those with a class name the corresponds with the `value=""` of the option currently selected, without affecting their `nth-child` styles. (E.g. selecting "green" on the dropdown would result in each list only showing `li` elements with class "item-green" appearing.)

Currently, when an option on the dropdown is selected the first time, everything works as expected. However, when the selected option changes on all succeeding tries, nothing on each list appears.

```js
var detach;

$("select").change(function() {
  var current = $("select option:selected").attr("value");
  var currentClass = ".item-" + current;

  $('.lists').show(0);

  $('.lists ul').each(function() {
    var detach = $(this).find("li").detach();
    var detachFiltered = detach.filter(currentClass);
    $(this).append(detachFiltered);
  });
});
```

```css
.lists {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>Choose a color:</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<div class="lists">
  <section>
    <h1>Set 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item-red">Burgundy</li>
      <li class="item-green">Chartreuse</li>
      <li class="item-blue">Cyan</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Set 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item-red">Crimson</li>
      <li class="item-green">Olive</li>
      <li class="item-blue">Cyan</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Set 3</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item-red">Scarlet</li>
      <li class="item-green">Lime</li>
      <li class="item-blue">Ultramarine</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of detaching/reattaching the `li` in the DOM your code can be made much more simple by just toggling a class on the relevant elements to display/hide them.

Note in the example below that I amended the classes on the `li` to have a common `.item` to make targeting them easier, and a separate class to determine the colour they belong to. Try this:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  var current = $(this).val();
  $('.lists').show().find('.item').removeClass('active').filter('.' + current).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.lists { display: none; }
.item { display: none; }
.item.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>Choose a color:</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<div class="lists">
  <section>
    <h1>Set 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item red">Burgundy</li>
      <li class="item green">Chartreuse</li>
      <li class="item blue">Cyan</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Set 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item red">Crimson</li>
      <li class="item green">Olive</li>
      <li class="item blue">Cyan</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Set 3</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item red">Scarlet</li>
      <li class="item green">Lime</li>
      <li class="item blue">Ultramarine</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```